# Making a QTextEdit capital

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I am trying to make all text in a QTextEdit capital, but currently am failing. This is my code and it does nothing.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionCapital_triggered()
{
    QTextCharFormat capital2;
    capital2.setFontCapitalization(QFont::AllUppercase);
    ui->textEdit->setCurrentCharFormat(capital2);
}
```

I am a java coder, so c++ is not my strong point

I also tried the following code with no success:

```
QFont font = ui->textEdit->font();
font.setCapitalization(QFont::AllUppercase);
ui->textEdit->setFont(font);
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: What do you want ? That any character entered in the TextEdit ends up Upper case'd, or that the current content of the TextEdit is converted to upper case letters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out not the most elegant solution, but it will do its job:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionCapital_triggered()
{
    QTextCursor c = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
    int current = c.position();
    if(capital)
    {
        QTextCharFormat capital2;
        capital2.setFontCapitalization(QFont::MixedCase);
        ui->textEdit->selectAll();
        ui->textEdit->setCurrentCharFormat(capital2);
        capital = false;
    }
    else
    {
        QTextCharFormat capital2;
        capital2.setFontCapitalization(QFont::AllUppercase);
        ui->textEdit->selectAll();
        ui->textEdit->setCurrentCharFormat(capital2);
        capital = true;
    }
    c = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
    c.setPosition(current);
    c.setPosition(current, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
    ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(c);
}
```

With this code you can switch between all Upper case and mixed case.
For some reason the setCurrentCharFormat only works when the text is selected.
So I had to get the current cursor position and then select all apply the FontCapitalization and then set the cursor back to where it was.